# How can this jQuery animation be optimized/smooth

Tags: jquery, html

Currently I am working on [this site](http://nicray.com).
On the page 'photographers' I am running a filter functionality which hides/shows the images corresponding to the photographers on the left site.

At this time there are 60 thumbnails to display and animation is not smooth. Later on there will be around 150 pictures.

How can I optimize this animation? Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Please ask a question, don't refer to your site and ask for debug.

Comment: I just thought it would be nice to have an example as everybody is able to use the code Inspector and see the script! So, if it isn't allowed, please delete this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Preload the images so that it doesn't flicker while it waits to
   download the new image (colored image should be preloaded)
2. Position the colored image absolutely over the original position,
       and then animate the opacity.
3. Use CSS3 transitions first, then JS/jQuery animations as a backup.

Comment: Nice answer! How can I force JS/jQuery to handle as a fallback?

Comment: Use Modernizr http://www.modernizr.com/ to check for CSS3 capabilities, then handle it in your JS.  You can do this by checking for the class csstransitions in the html element, or by doing if (Modernizr.csstransitions) {}